# Filtering data out from a pivot table using a table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I'm trying to filter data out from a pivot table that I have already created. Instead of hard-coding data that I want to filter out from the fields "apples" and "oranges", I'd like to create a table for each field on a separate worksheet and somehow code something to pull data from those tables. This is because I'd need to update the "filtered out" tables almost weekly and it'll be updated by many people - it'd be easier to update the tables than continuously hard-code things. The code is shown below, grateful for any help with this!

`ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Apples")
        .PivotItems("A").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("B").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("C").Visible = False
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Oranges")
        .PivotItems("A").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("B").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("C").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("D").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("E").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("F").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("G").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("H").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("I").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("J").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("K").Visible = False`

Comment: Hi Sami. Approximately how many pivotitems are in these fields? Hundreds? Thosands? Tens of thousands?   Reason I ask is that I have some fairly simple routines that will be fine if the numbers of unique items in the pivottable are smallish and some very complicated but fast routines if the number is large

Comment: Hi jeffrey, there are hundreds of pivotitems in the fields. It might go up to thousands but nothing more than say, two thousand.

Answer (score 0):

Sami: See my code and blogpost at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/12/03/inversely-filter-a-pivot-based-on-an-external-range/